# Select2 problems with search and initSelection

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2

Select2 code :

```
$(".js-select").select2( {
    placeholder: "Select Something",

    ajax: {
        // The number of milliseconds to wait for the user to stop typing before issuing the ajax request
        delay: 400,
        url: "<?php echo site_url('main/get_items') ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: "true",

        data: function (params) {
            return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page,

            };
        },

        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                    return { id: obj.id, text: obj.nume };
                })
            };
        },
    },

    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
         var data = {id: "1", text: "test relation"};
         callback(data);
    },
});
```

HTML :

```
<select class="js-select" name="judet" style="width: 100%" required> </select>
```

1. First problem :
   Using initSelection doesn’t work :

Code :

```
initSelection : function (element, callback) {
    var data = {id: "1", text: "test relation"};
    callback(data);
},
```

I see the “test relation” text but when i submit i get no value for the id.

2. Secound problem :

When i try to select 1 item from the dropdown .... Select2 initializes a search ... I need select2 to run search only when users type something for search ...

Webpage : http://www.my-web-projects.com/ajax/main/table -> button ADD ->dropdown Select 1 and select 2

Answer (score 1):

> First problem : Using initSelection doesn’t work :

This sounds like a bug in Select2, it should attempt to create the `<option>` elements so the value gets sent. If you can wrap up the bug [in a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) and [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/new) that'd be helpful.

> When i try to select 1 item from the dropdown .... Select2 initializes a search ... I need select2 to run search only when users type something for search ...

You should be able to achieve this by using `minimumInputLength` and setting it to `1`. We use this [in the AJAX example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) so the request is only sent off when the user searches.

```
$element.select2({
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Comment: I have tryed minimumInputLength but then I have to write something in the search to be able to see the list. I don't want that i want to see the list and make search only if user types something ...

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for then, you are phrasing it like `minimumInputLength`. Your description is very vague and its not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I will use "minimumInputLength: 1" and look for a option to fix my first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var data = {id: "1", text: "test relation"};
```

to

```
var data = [{id: "1", text: "test relation"}];
```

## EDITED

```
$(".js-select").select2({/* */}).select2("data", [{"id":"1","text":"test relation"}]);
```

Comment: I was looking into your code and I wasn't able to find the class "js-tari-data-array" that you are using in the code. Can you point out, or better yet, show the usage of this class?

Comment: I have change to a smaller description and added the HTML

Comment: Did you remove the initSelection directive from the code? I don't see it in the live page.

Comment: I have modified the test page - see EDIT option

Comment: In the log, it gives a "An invalid form control with name='****' is not focusable" error, are you applying any validations? If not, add a "novalidate" clause to your form and then try again.

Comment: the edit work good ... that error is for select 1 and select 2 you can see the option but the ID is null so it request that you select something .. If you change to a value it will work ...This is the problem I have with iniSelection i dose not set the ID

Comment: I guess when you put an initSelection, it doesn't require it to be part of the select box, as you might notice once the data is loaded from the URL, it shows options under the selection, however, by default there is no option, even when initSelection is given the option, my guess is you need to put in the default <option value="1">test relation</option> for this to work.

Comment: yes the records are added by ajax request but there has to be on option to add the selected record to ..... I really don't want to add it by html input ..

Comment: `.select2('data', newData)` was removed in 4.0.0 for "too much magic" reasons.